# How to render an image?

Tags: rendering, image

I can choose the location of the render image but I can't find the render button. I find everywhere in the panel but there is no. Please help

Answer (score 3):

To render an image, you need to press "Render" on the top menu and click "Render Image"
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I finished render